# What is the relation between Gröbner basis and syzygies?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, computational-algebra

Let $I=(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5) $ an ideal in $S=\mathbb {C}[w,x,y,z ]$.

$f_1=w^2-xz $

$f_2=wx-yz$

$f_3=x^2-wy$

$f_4=xy-z^2$

$f_5=y^2-wz $

I want to compute the syzygies of $S/I $ using Gröbner basis.

I know the definition of syzygies and  I need to know the $S$-graded minimal free resolution for $S/I $ to compute the syzygies.

What is the relation between  Gröbner basis and syzygies?
I noticed that $G $={$f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5$} is a Gröbner basis of $I $.

Comment: Gröbner bases for $I$ with Lex: $z^5-w^5, yw^2-z^3, yz^2-w^3, y^2-zw, xw-yz, xz-w^2, xy-z^2, x^2-yw$ and GRevLex: $yz-xw, xz-w^2, y^2-zw, xy-z^2, x^2-yw, z^3-yw^2$ (found using Macaulay2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F = (f_1, \dots, f_5)\in S^5$ then $F$ is a Gröbner basis of the ideal $I = \langle f_1, \dots, f_5 \rangle$ if and only if every syzygy $(g_1, \dots, g_5)$ of the leading monomial $\mathop{LM}(I)$ can be lifted to a syzygy of $F$.

You can find details about the connection between Gröbner basis and syzygies for example in *Computational Commutative Algebra 1* by **Kreuzer and Robbiano** and in *Using Algebraic Geometry* by **Cox, Little and O'Shea**.